# Dynamic content load in Telerik Tabstrip

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik

In my app i have an entity called "Collections", each collection has a type. I want to load these collection into a tabstrip. Each tab is generated dynamically depending on the number of types:

```
@{
  Html.Telerik().TabStrip()
      .Name("CollectionTabStrip")
      .HtmlAttributes(new {@class = "mainTabStrip"})
      .Items(tabstrip =>
      {
       foreach (var type in Model.MediaCollectionTypes)
         {
          tabstrip.Add()
          .Text(type.Name)
          .HtmlAttributes(new {@class = "TabStripLi-1"})
          .ContentHtmlAttributes(new {style = "width: 589px; min-height: 400px;"})
          .LoadContentFrom("Collections", "MediaManager", new {typeId = type.ID, mediaId = Model.MediaID});
          }
       })
       .SelectedIndex(0)
       .ClientEvents(c => c.OnContentLoad("onTabStripContentLoad"))
       .Render();

   }
```

Now the problem is that the content is loaded on clicking the tab, but I need it all to be loaded on `page/tabstrip` load. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

you can use tabstrip's .OnLoad("onLoad") event and call a javascript function to load your content.

Reference: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/tabstrip/clientsideevents